# Is it possible to use jQuery for HTML parsing?

Tags: jquery, html, parsing, html-parsing

Just out of curiosity, I am trying to see if it is possible to use jQuery to read a HTML file so that I can use it to output some values of some html elements? I am looking for some functionality like what Firebug provides i.e. Firebug lets me use the `$()` on any webpage so what I am trying to achieve is:

- I have a bunch of HTML files
- I need to load each one of them and using jQuery, I want to extract some information pertaining to some HTML elements

So maybe use Python to load each file and then use jQuery to parse the HTML somehow. I don't know the right terminology to use to describe this requirement but any suggestions? Maybe I am looking for a command line jQuery execution engine?

**EDIT:**
Or maybe I'm looking for a scripting language that provides the `$()` functionality. I looked at Beautiful Soup but I'm still curious about jQuery like functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe I'll get another answer but I just found the closest match here:

`http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyquery`

It looks awesome as of now.

Comment: The awesome power of Google :)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps take a look at [`lxml`](http://codespeak.net/lxml/)? The [`lxml.cssselect`](http://codespeak.net/lxml/cssselect.html) submodule allows you to select objects in a manner very similar to jQuery's selectors.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using python then probably beautiful soup is a better solution

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

Answer (score 0):

I've used [PHP: dom](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) quite successfully for scraping webpages.  For simple data extraction getElementById and getElementByTagName are usually plenty powerful enough.